# Databound DataField not getting populated

Tags: asp.net, sql, web-applications, webforms

I'm currently analyzing the code behind for a web application.  The Default page contains a GridView with several bound DataFields that are supposed to be populated, when the page loads and reloads, with data based on a URL parameter that's passed on initial load.  The way it works in summary is this:

-I have a `GridView1_Init` method that is called when the page loads, this retrieves data using an OldDbConnection and a URL parameter appended as part of the OleDbCommand SQL statement.

-The data is read and stored in the Web.config file.  At this point, when debugging, I can see and verify the there is data being retrieved.

-Now I'm calling a `GridView1_RowDataBound` method to populate each row.  I have it in the Default.aspx page within the GirdView parameters as `OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"`

My problem is that this method never gets called for one of the URL parameters I'm passing and as a result the Databound rows in the GridView don't get populated and the page displays nothing.  I have another URL parameter I use to test and it works perfectly with that one, i.e. the page loads with the Gridview displaying all the data as expected.  I'm not sure why the method `GridView1_RowDataBound` is getting called for one URL parameter, but not for the other.  I've debugged using both and also ran the query in SQL Server Management Studio and I am getting data back for both.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: post some code. there's no telling what's going on from your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did a little more digging using Visual Studio and SQL Server Management Studio and first determined that the gridview was using a different stored procedure, than the one I was referencing, to populate the grid.  Second, after rummaging through the database, I discovered that the table being referenced for data to populate the grid was empty.  After inserting some test data, I went back and reran the application and finally had some data being displayed in the grid.  Always the little things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure.. but try these 1-on the page load define a GridView1.datasource=....;
GridView1.Databind();
2-check the html tags are formed correctly.